# Makefile with directories

Tags: c++, makefile, directory

My Makefile was fine. However, now I want to have a folder named "Makefile" and a folder named "main", where the first will contain my Makefiles and the second will contain files that are meant to be the `main()` of my my project, k-d GeRaF.

For now, the header files lie in the same folder. That folder also contains Makefile folder and main folder.

Here is my makefile (have tried many combinations, this is the last attempt):

```
OBJS    = main_par_auto.o
SOURCE  = ../main/main_par_auto.cpp
HEADER  =   ../Division_Euclidean_space.h   ../Find_diameter.h  ../Find_k_max.h ../Householder.h    ../IO.h ../Mean_variance.h  ../Point.h  ../Random_generator.h   ../Random_kd_forest.h   ../Tree.h   ../Auto_random_kd_forest.h
OUT     =   geraf
CXX = g++
FLAGS   =   -pthread    -std=c++0x  -DRKD_PAR   -O3 -Wall

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX)  $(OBJS) -o $(OUT)   $(FLAGS)

# create/compile the individual files >>separately<< 
main_par_auto.o:    main_par_auto.cpp
    $(CXX) -c   ../main/main_par_auto.cpp   $(FLAGS)

.PHONY : all
# clean house
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `main_par_auto.cpp', needed by `main_par_auto.o'.  Stop.
```

I am executing this command: `make -f Makefile/Makefile_par_auto` in order to compile.

What am I missing please?

This is the big picture ( literally :) )
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `main_par_auto.o:    ../main/main_par_auto.cpp`?

Comment: Yes @jadhachem. `make: *** No rule to make target \`../main/main_par_auto.cpp\`, needed by `main_par_auto.o'.  Stop.`

Comment: Are the paths relative to the working directory or to the path of the makefile?

Comment: @Wintermute I am not sure what you asked. I made a screenshot, did this help? I think the first. I am running make from the folder that appears in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths in the Makefile have to be relative to the working directory (the directory from which you run make), not to the directory that contains the Makefile. With

```
main_par_auto.o: main/main_par_auto.cpp
    $(CXX) -c main/main_par_auto.cpp $(FLAGS)
```

you should get the expected results.

Note that it is very unusual to expect a user to invoke `make` this way. Normally, you'd expect to have a Makefile in the directory where you call `make` (that may or may not go on to use other makefiles in other directories).

Comment: I am planning to have a make in the calling directory, which will call the corresponding Makefile from the Makefile folder. I will test now.